# why a variable calculation would take more time if inserted in nested function?

Tags: python, global-variables, local-variables

In the example code here

```
def foo1():
    a=1
    b=2
    x=a+b
    
    def foo2():
        print(x)
    if some_condition==True:
        foo2()
foo1()
```

if I move x=a+b to foo2(), would time taken to execute increase?

I tried to profile my code similar to the example. In my case foo1() always executes but foo2() rarely does so whenever I have the intent to print x, I calculate x inside foo2() and then go on.
so when in code version 1, x used to calculate everytime as many times I call the function foo1() so cumulative time reported by cProfiler was like 4 secs, now if I put x in foo2(), it foo2() is not called as often as foo1(), it is still taking around the same.
to be clear in code1 , time taken per call for x is 0.004sec and in code 2 its 0.052sec.

Comment: `x=a+b` takes the same amount of time no matter where it is.  It is impossible to help with your specific problem without seeing some real code.  Performance measurement is very tricky, and I/O (like `print` statements) will always interfere.

Comment: Accessing variables in a closure does change which bytecode instructions are used for loading and assigning them (`{LOAD,STORE}_FAST` vs `{LOAD,STORE}_DEREF`). I'm not sure if that has any significant performance implications though. I kinda doubt there's any, since afaik both work as direct array lookups.

Comment: For questions about performance like this, it is good that you've tried to profile first, but don't describe how you profiled your code *with prose*, provide the *actual code that produces the results you report*. That way, we can begin to discuss this without *guessing what you are doing*.

Comment: @Brian61354270 both of those are much more optimized than loading a global name.

Comment: Anyway, it isn't even clear what the actual results are, you are saying that " it is still taking around the same." but your question is "why a variable calculation would take more time if inserted in nested function?" ... so is it taking more time or around the same time? Note, something like `x=a+b` shouldn't take much fo any time at all, running `a = 0; b = 1`, and `x = a + b` **one million times takes** about  `0.027442030957899988` seconds on my laptop which is from 2016. So this is probably not contributing much to your performance either way

Comment: if I isolate out *only* the addition, I get `0.01845534797757864` seconds for running it one million times.